# How to get an AbstractClientPlayer for all players?

Tags: minecraft-modding, modding

I'm working on an minecraft forge mod (1.8.8). I have en custom (ownable) entity and want to set its texture to the texture of its owner, because it's a mini version of the owner.

I found out that i can get the texture of players with `AbstractClientPlayer#getLocationSkin()`, but i can't figure out how to access either `EntityOtherPlayerMP` or `EntityPlayerSP`, which implement `AbstractClientPlayer`, in my custom renderer. Is there a way to get all `AbstractClientPlayer`, regardless of SP or MP? I can access the GameProfile and i have the EntityPlayer of the owner.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the solution is fairly simple: I was able to simply cast the `EntityPlayer` to an `AbstractClientPlayer`! I got the EntityPlayer with my EntityLiving, because its an ownable creature:

```
@Override
protected ResourceLocation getEntityTexture(EntityLiving entity) {
    IEntityOwnable creature = (IEntityOwnable) entity;
    AbstractClientPlayer player = (AbstractClientPlayer) creature.getOwner();
    return player.getLocationSkin();
}
```

Comment: This of course only works if the entity is an `IEntityOwnable` which you stated it was, but you might want to insert an `instanceof` check just to avoid potential problems.

Comment: @Draco18s Generally, yes, but this i given when i set it.

Comment: I think it isn't even possible to get an plain EntityPlayer on Client-Side. This is inside a renderer, so it will only get called on a Game Client.